# Android Asynctask returning multiple values

Tags: android, image, opencv, android-asynctask

Is there a way to return multiple values from an Asynctask in android? I have a task that returns a bitmap but I am running opencv and I have an two ints I need to update to the GUI for and x and y position.

Is there a way to send a bitmap and two integers to the onPostExecute() method?

Thanks!

Comment: create your own object that holds a bitmap and two integers?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a private member variable for the task and load data into it during the doInBackground and the read it during the onPostExecute:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private int xLoc = 0;
    private int yLoc = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // do some pre-processing, if you want
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...params) {
        // do something to get the new x,y values
        xLoc = 100;
        yLoc = 200;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        // do something with the new x, y values
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "x = " + xLoc + ", y = " + yLoc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```